# Nginx configuration for Wordpress in a directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, nginx

I have a Rails app configured with nginx with its root at /var/www/apps/example/current/public. It's accessed at https://www.example.com. That all works great. I decided to add a blog, and I wanted to go with Wordpress. I installed it in a different directory on the server, /var/www/apps/blog, and I want to be able to access it by going to https://www.example.com/blog

Below is my nginx config:

```
server {
  listen      443;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/certs/example.com.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/certs/example.com.key;

  server_name www.example.com;
  root         /var/www/apps/example/current/public;
  passenger_enabled on;
  rails_env production;

  client_max_body_size 100M;
  client_body_buffer_size 256k;

  error_page  404              /404.html;

  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
    root   html;
  }

  location /blog {
    root /var/www/apps;

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
      try_files $uri =404;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
    }
  }
}
```

I can navigate to example.com/blog and it takes me there without any issues. The problem comes when I enable pretty URLs and try to view a post. It circumvents the /blog directory and hits my Rails app, ending up with a 404. I see the following error in /var/log/nginx/error.log:

```
2016/06/30 17:24:32 [error] 7035#0: *20 "/var/www/apps/blog/hello-world/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 199.27.128.198, server: www.example.com, request: "GET /blog/hello-world/ HTTP/1.1", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/blog/"
```

Adding an `index index.php` directive doesn't fix the problem, it merely then states that `/var/www/apps/blog/hello-world/index.php` is not found instead.

Any ideas? I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`try_files $uri=404;` is not enough for pretty permalinks.

To enable pretty permalinks, you need to change it to:

```
location /blog {
  root /var/www/apps/blog;

  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

Or, try [non-root try_files redirect](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/#non-root-try-files-to-url-redirect):

```
location /blog {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

Comment: Close enough that I'll mark this as the solution since it pointed me in the right direction. Simply adding `try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;` in the first example you gave did the trick.